# Unable to login to Django admin panel after implementing custom user model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I've done for customizing the User model, but I'm unable to log in to the admin panel with the superuser account I created. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

users/user.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from ..managers.user import UserManager

class User(AbstractUser):
    objects = UserManager()
```

manager/user.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_superuser(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        return self.create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, username=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The username field must set')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)

        return user
```

user/serializer.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password
from rest_framework import serializers  # type: ignore # noqa: I201

User = get_user_model()


class UserReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username')


class UserWriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(validators=[validate_password], write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('password', 'username')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        username = validated_data.get('username')
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)

        return user
```

settings/base.py

```
from typing import List

DEBUG = True  # This should be 'False' in prod mode
SECRET_KEY = NotImplemented

ALLOWED_HOSTS: List[str] = ['*']
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS: List[str] = []

INTERNAL_IPS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
]

APPEND_SLASH = False

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Third party
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'django_filters',
    'storages',

    # App
    'cores.authentication.apps.AuthenticationConfig',
    'cores.users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'cores.cards.apps.CardsConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'cores.project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'cores.project.asgi.application'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cores.project.wsgi.application'



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'trinion',
        'USER': 'trinion',
        'PASSWORD': 'trinion',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 600,
    }
}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True



MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'  # type: ignore # noqa: F821

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'  # type: ignore # noqa: F821

DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 10485760  # 10MB
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 10485760  # 10MB

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

settings/rest_framework.py

```
from datetime import timedelta

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=365),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=30),
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': True,
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': [
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
        'rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',),
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json',
}
```

Environment
Django 3.2
Python 3.9
PostgreSQL
Docker (for development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be here, have you tried login in with the email as the username

```
    return self.create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

def create_user(self, email, username=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
```

as per the code above, you're interchanging the fields username and email while calling the method self.create_user.
soln:

```
    return self.create_user(email, username, password, **extra_fields)

def create_user(self, email, username=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
```

Comment: You are right. I could login with email as a username. God, you save my day. Thank you! Could you please explain a little more about this?

Comment: while calling a python method/function, you need to pass arguments as specified in the method/function and in the same order. But you can also send arguments with the key = value syntax.This way the order of the arguments does not matter.